# Why use SaveChangesAsync if parallelism is not supported?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When using EF Context and calling SaveChangesAsync in two separate async methods you can cause a race condition on the context. Why use SaveChangesAsync() if it can cause such problems?

[Microsoft Docs - SaveChangesAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontext.savechangesasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) - has the following remark.

Remarks
Multiple active operations on the same context instance are not supported. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context.

```
public class AccountManager
  {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public AccountManager(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task UpdateAccountStatus(int id, Status status)
    {
        var acc = await _dbContext.Account.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        acc.Status = status;
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task UpdateAccountName(int id, string name)
    {
        var acc = await _dbContext.Account.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
        acc.Name= name;
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public class AccountOrchestrator
  {
    private readonly AccountManager _accountManager;

    public AccountOrchestrator(AccountManager accountManager)
    {
        _accountManager= accountManager;
    }

    // Race Condition
    public async Task UpdateAccount(int id, Status status, string Name)
    {
        var token1 = _accountManager.UpdateStatus(id, status);
        var token2 = _accountManager.UpdateName(id, name);

        await token2;
        await token1;       
    }
}
```

I would expect multiple async operations on the context would be supported. Else why use async at all if you must await inline every time?

Comment: It's not for issuing multiple operations on the context itself. Async processing can be used to issue an operation on the context and another on the UI at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case **async** means that `SaveChangesAsync()` will send the command to the database, release the current thread to do more work, and continue execution of your method after the database has completed the operations.

This is particularly useful in two cases:

1. In desktop applications, this can relieve your UI thread to process events and keep your application responsive and nice looking.
2. Server applications, where incoming requests are usually processed by a thread from the thread-pool: the async method will release the thread until the operation is performed by the db, thus allowing the thread to service other requests.

See more [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 1):

Async != parallelism. All async does is unblock the thread so that other work can happen such as fulfilling other requests.